# What are {curly brackets} for in Gnu-Apl?

Tags: syntax, gnu, apl

What are {curly brackets} for in GNU-APL?

As far as I know, GNU-APL uses the APL Iso standard.

Comment: A search for the opening brace in http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html suggests that braces are a part of the syntax for Direct Functions (Lambdas), both named and unnamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU APL implements direct definition notation, lambdas, not unlike NGN/APL and Dyalog APL.